# latitude and longitude of current position in openlayer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am trying to get the current location latitude and longitude values. is there any method to get lat and long values? I am trying to put maker by getting latitude and longitude value of current position.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for but here are a couple of ways to get lat long based on mouse click or location:

Mouse Click Lat and Lon:

```
map.on('click', function(evt){
    console.info(evt.pixel);
    console.info(map.getPixelFromCoordinate(evt.coordinate));
    console.info(ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate));
    var coords = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);
    var lat = coords[1];
    var lon = coords[0];
    var locTxt = "Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + lon;
    // coords is a div in HTML below the map to display
    document.getElementById('coords').innerHTML = locTxt;
});
```

Mouse move/location lat and long:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
    //Same code as in click event
});
```

Not exactly sure what "getting latitude and longitude value of current position." means in your post

Comment: It's directly available in the [MapBrowserEvent](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.MapBrowserEvent.html)
```javascript
map.on('click', evt => console.log(evt.coordinate))
```

Comment: `import {fromLonLat, toLonLat} from 'ol/proj';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use either:

1. `var lonlat  = ol.proj.toLonLat(evt.coordinate);`
2. Or `var lonlat = ol.proj.transform(evt.coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');`

And get it as: `alert("latitude : " + lonlat[1] + ", longitude : " + lonlat[0]);`

Within:
`map.on('click', function (evt) { }`